# Basic query study item - suggestions?

Tags: sql

I have a study question that I stumped me. Any suggestions would be most appreciated! Just some basic examples would nudge me in the right direction.  Thanks!

You receive a request for a list of student quiz information entered into a database during the 2017 calendar year. SQL query that would return a record for (a) each score a student, (b) student name, (c) which class the quiz was for, and (d) when the score was entered into the database.

Comment: Can you share your table(s) structure?

Comment: Table(s) name and structure please including the column names

Comment: Isn't this the very definition of "homework"? There is no attempt, no problem to help with or question (except for the actual homework) .

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Do not post code or additional information in comments

Answer (score 0):

If you still need to build the tables and query them yourself, it would be something like this. You can read the comments and see what each syntax is doing

```
  --CREATING the tables for the student information
  create table quizinfo (
               StudentId INT,
               Name VARCHAR(500),
               Score INT,
               Class VARCHAR(500),
               DateEntered smalldatetime,
               Year INT
            )

    --Inserting data to the table
      Insert into quizinfo values ('1', 'Ken Lee', '95', 'Math', '2017-05-
      20', ' 2017')
      Insert into quizinfo values ('2', 'Maria Chen', '100', 'Math', '2017-
      05-20', '2017')
      Insert into quizinfo values ('3', 'Sophia Reyes', '100', 'Math', 
      '2017-05-20', '2015')

    --Selecting the data from the table where the year is only for 2017. The 
    --WHERE year = 2017 makes sure that it only picks up rows for 2017
    SELECT Name, Score, Class, DateEntered, Year FROM quizinfo
    WHERE year = '2017'
```